# Android Studio “Button Tapped!”

Tags: android, button, logging, android-studio

Thank you for reading this question.

I’m new to learning to develop apps for Android, and have almost zero experience coding.  The instructor of the course I’m taking used the following code to make a button added to our Android Studio Project send the message, “Button Tapped!” to the logs to log a specific button-click every time the specific button is clicked:

```
public void clickfunction(View view){Log.i(“Info”, “Button Tapped!”);}
```

It’s taken two days to get to the point where Android Studio 1.4.1 on my iMac running OS X 10.11.1 with the latest updates installed to Launch an Android Emulator.

Even then, “The Android App My App Test” Stopped,” appears when the button is clicked in the launched emulator using a customized Android Vitual Device (AVD)configured as an 8” DROID TURBO With 3GB of RAM at 1440 x 2560. At least the logs show the following errors, so technically, “The button works,” in that it sends the following messages to the logs. It does not display, “Button Tapped!” in the logs.:

Android Monitor

```
11-06 11:23:39.600 3298-3298/com.example.chris.myapplicationtest     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 11:23:39.600 3298-3298/com.example.chris.myapplicationtest     E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.chris.myapplicationtest, PID: 3298
11-06 11:23:39.600 3298-3298/com.example.chris.myapplicationtest E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method   clickfunctio(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick   attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton  with id 'button'
11-06 11:23:39.600 3298-3298/com.example.chris.myapplicationtest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:310)
11-06 11:23:39.600 3298-3298/com.example.chris.myapplicationtest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:269)
11-06 11:23:39.600 3298-3298/com.example.chris.myapplicationtest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
11-06 11:23:39.600 3298-3298/com.example.chris.myapplicationtest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
11-06 11:23:39.600 3298-3298/com.example.chris.myapplicationtest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-06 11:23:39.600 3298-3298/com.example.chris.myapplicationtest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-06 11:23:39.600 3298-3298/com.example.chris.myapplicationtest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-06 11:23:39.600 3298-3298/com.example.chris.myapplicationtest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-06 11:23:39.600 3298-3298/com.example.chris.myapplicationtest E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-06 11:23:39.600 3298-3298/com.example.chris.myapplicationtest E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-06 11:23:39.600 3298-3298/com.example.chris.myapplicationtest E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-06 11:23:41.390 3298-3298/com.example.chris.myapplicationtest I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3298 SIG: 9
```

Event Log

```
11:00:17 AM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
11:00:19 AM Gradle build finished with 10 error(s) in 1s 984ms
11:09:02 AM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
11:09:03 AM Gradle build finished with 2 error(s) in 1s 426ms
11:09:26 AM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
11:09:40 AM Gradle build finished in 14s 275ms
11:21:02 AM Session 'app': running
11:23:38 AM IllegalStateException: no segments available. offset = 3921
11:23:38 AM Platform and Plugin Updates: The following component is ready to update: Android Auto Desktop Head Unit emulator
11:23:46 AM IllegalStateException: no segments available. offset = 3654
11:26:26 AM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
11:26:28 AM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
```

Again,

Thank You for your time!

Comment: did you define onclick in xml of button

Comment: "Could not find method   clickfunctio(View) in a parent"? Where is your clickfunctio(View).?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo error: change `clickfunctio` to `clickfunction` in your XML file.

Answer (score 1):

*onClick method name mismatched*

Because added `clickfunctio` in `android:onClick` in Button xml as method but in code method name is `clickfunction`.